# Truncate String with CSS Ellipsis in the Left Side

Tags: html, css

I know it sounds weird, but I need to acomplish this in the left side of my string:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

For example: Instead of "Hello..." I need it to be "...olleH"

Do anybody know if there is way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try with { direction: rtl; } CSS property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.truncate_class {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60px;
  direction: rtl;
  margin-left: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.truncate_class:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  content: "...";
}
```

```html
<p class="truncate_class">12154543554534351432123</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: My hero! Thanks!

Comment: This method would output **... Hello**, not **...olleH** as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dir: rlt` will only swap the default left-to-right layout.
To flip each letter backwards, you'll need the [unicode-bidi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) property.

```css
.toTruncate {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  max-width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="toTruncate">Hello John Doe</p>
```